# Durable vs. transient subscriptions

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I am integrating several .Net modules using pub/sub messaging using RabbitMQ and MassTransit. Most of the message subscription shall be durable. But some shall be transient. When a consumer dies the messages shall not be stored and already queued messages shall be discarded.

In each module I create 1 bus with 2 receive endpoints. One is configured as durable and non-auto-delete. The other one is configured as non-durable and auto-delete. Each gets its own set of consumers. This works as expected.

Now I am trying to implement request/response messages. Here comes the problem because now the sender has to decide to which exchange to route to. And that is wrong as I want receiver to decide whether to use durable or transient queue.

My questions:

1. Is there a better way how to support durable and transient subscription at the same time?
2. Why is MassTransit binding message exchange to an endpoint exchange that is bound to an endpoint queue? Why cannot the message exchange be directly bound to the endpoint queue?
3. Lets assume that all request consumers in one module are either durable or transient. Is it possible to declare one "module"-exchange which is then bound to either durable or transient queue? So the sender addresses the module exchange and module decides to which queue to bind. How to convince MassTransit to do so?
   [image]
4. A module is using durable subscriptions that survive through restarts of module and also broker. After some time, admin (so in run-time of the system) decides to disconnect this module from the system. Can the module somehow unsubscribe everything and let MassTransit to remove the durable exchanges and queues?

Answer (score 0):

Your question starts with request/response sent to an unknown endpoint, and ends with removing exchanges. These are different things, I suppose.

I cannot answer point-by-point, just will try to clear up things.

Request/response by definition requires you to know where you send stuff. As per MassTransit convention, the endpoint address is always an exchange/queue pair address. Therefore, you cannot let receiver decide who will handle this message, it will be delivered to the exchange/queue of the endpoint where you send it to.

About the "unsubscribe" - MassTransit deletes nothing. You have to clean up the binding that is not being used manually or by using the management API.

Comment: Yeah I put a lot of stuff there. The common topic are durable and transient subscriptions...

I understand there has to be a known address for req/res. I just want to have 1 address that I give to sender and let receiver to decide whether it is queued to durable or transient queue (I updated question with picture). Question is whether I am able to customize MT to create one exchange and 2 queues? Looking at MT code it seems I have to change half of the endpoint creation code and not sure it will work afterwards.

Comment: I can actually create 3rd endpoint. But it starts to be complicated and I suspect there is better way that I dont see.
BTW Thx for the unsubscribe answer. Answers question 4 perfectly.

Comment: Each receive endpoint is a combination of one exchange and one queue with the endpoint name.